# Laravel Eloquent joins between tables unrelated?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am having an issue. I have two separate databases, one for films and one for followers. This is so films can have specific film data (title, image, director) etc and then I have a follow table so a user can follow a film. Basically this is just a cross table, all it has in it is id, userID, filmID. This is generally used for if a user goes to a film page, it checks if a record exists and if so it does x,y,z.

Now on a users page I am trying to list all the things they follow. So currently I can say.

```
    $following = Follow::where('userId', '=', $user->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

And that will return me all of the things a user is following. However my issue is that I don't want to display the film ID, I want to display the picture, title, director etc. That Information is in the films table however. So how can I say do a call that gets all Follow instances but also grabs the film row attached to it. so that I can go.
echo $following->title and it will display the film title. Thanks

Comment: So do a join?
`Follow::where('userId', '=', $user->id)->join('film', 'film.id', '=', 'follow.filmId')`
Honestly, this syntax is a lot more confusing than just doing sql...
http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=3490

Comment: So I did that, but now the $following->title method isnt quite working. Like if I var dump $following all the data is together and their, but I must have to access it differently?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up solving it, this allows for the same process of $myquery->attribute without being super complicated.

```
    $followingUsers = Follow::where('userId','=', $user->id)->get();
    $followingFilms = Follow::where('userId','=', $user->id)->get();
    $followedFilms = new stdClass();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($followingFilms as $follow)
    {
        $followedFilm = new stdClass();
        $film = Film::where('id','=', $follow->filmId)->first();
        $followedFilm->title = $film->title;
        $followedFilm->coverUrl = $film->image;
        $followedFilm->slug = $film->slug;
        $followedFilm->id = $film->id;
        $followedFilms->$i = $followedFilm;
        $i++;
    }
```

This takes each object of the follow table, makes a sql request to get the information and then compiles it all into object $followedFilms.

Comment: Man, all of this when in sql all you'd have to do is `SELECT * FROM followingUsers f STRAIGHT_JOIN followingFilms ff ON ff.id=f.filmId;`Granted, I would format that a bit differently. Include which DB it's coming from, etc etc. But I really don't understand why this exists...